# Can't get to desktop after 16.10 to 17.04 update

Tags: 17.04, 16.10

I just updated to 17.04 but now the keyboard doesn't work (on laptop or usb) so I can't sign in to fix anything.  I can't even connect to wifi or use an ethernet cable to fix some of the packages.  When I try to enable eth0 it says "device not found" but the cable is plugged in.

What do I do?

Please help, any input is useful.

'lscpi -vnn | grep Ethernet' output

Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8618/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)

Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Controller [1025:1094]

Comment: when you try to enable eth0? so keyboard works? ok we need the output of `lspci -vnn | grep Ethernet` edit your question and attached it in the image

Comment: I tried going through recovery mode in a root shell, but it doesn't let me enable it.  The 17.04 login screen itself is completely unresponsive